# Auto backup or copy files onto another drive with ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: server, backup

I have a Dell Poweredge 860 with Ubuntu server 16.04 on it and I need a way to automatically back it up like copying ALL files on one drive to the other even the os files too like an AUTO backup system so I don't lose my data during a power loss and my UPS dies or a drive fails.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at "rdiffbackup". I use it in the office (although I confess I did not set it up) and it works a treat. It makes a backup of full systems, and I have used the backups a few times to restore a system.

Sorry I can't give full details as I didn't set it up, I just know that's what's used.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make a cron task `sudo crontab -e` and use rsync on it, it's a powerfull tool using incremental copy.